# Can the 90/180 Schengen Visa for a US Citizen be staggered?

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, europe

I stayed for two months from March 10th to April 27 (almost 2 months). Would the remaining month I *didn't use* still be available for me if I were to return in July?

Comment: You could even stay more than a month, because, come July, March does not count anymore as it's more than 90 days in the past.

Comment: Thanks @Annoyed . How does March get discounted though?

Comment: Looks like I made a mistake, you should return more than 90 days *after April 27* for that to work. It's a sliding 180 days window: So if you come back after 90 days (say in August) and you have one month left, you can use that month first. At the end of the month (it's September now), the very first day of your first stay does not count anymore because it's now more than 180 days in the past. And so on, until you reach 90 days again. It even works if you only have one day left. It's safer to use the calculator rather than rely on my logic, though ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The official EU site now has a calculator to tell you how many days you can stay, after you input all your previous stays: http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html.

The UI is pretty weak, but it works.